# Non-invasively extensible Adapter for classes with template member functions

Tags: c++, c++17, adapter

I want to write an `Adapter` for two different classes `ClassA` and `ClassB` - neither are mine and both have template member functions. I want to use `Adapter` as argument of a pure virtual member function of a class `Base` in order to avoid overloading of `Base::do_something` for `ClassA` and `ClassB` since a lot of classes will inherit from `Base`.

The code below is based on static polymorphism and shows how far I have got. However, extending the `Adapter` to work with a third class, say `ClassC`, always requires to change `Adapter`.

I wonder if there is a better way out there to write such an adapter which also can be easily extended (like in the classical adapter pattern). It would be great if someone could give me a good hint.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <variant>

template<class ...Ts>
struct overloaded : Ts...
{
    overloaded(const Ts&... args) : Ts(args)... { }
    using Ts::operator()...;
};

struct ClassA
{
template <class T>
std::string get_type() const {return typeid(T()).name();}
};

struct ClassB
{
template <class T>
void old_print_type() const {std::cout << typeid(T()).name();}
};

struct Adapter
{
    template <class Adaptee>
    Adapter (Adaptee* a) : adaptee(a) {};

    template <class T>
    void print_type() const
    {
        std::visit(overloaded(
            [](ClassA* v){ std::cout << v->get_type<T>();},
            [](ClassB* v){ v->old_print_type<T>();}
        ),adaptee);
    }

    using adaptee_type = std::variant<ClassA*,ClassB*>;

    adaptee_type adaptee;
};

struct Base
{
    virtual void do_something(const Adapter&) = 0;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

int main()
{
    ClassA a;
    ClassB b;
    Adapter adapterA(&a);
    Adapter adapterB(&b);

    adapterA.print_type<double>();
    std::cout << std::endl;
    adapterB.print_type<double>();
}
```

Comment: But how can I store a function pointer to a template member function?

Comment: By ignoring me, because I completely misread your question ...

Comment: Ah ok, I really wondered if it can be that simple.

Comment: Double dispatch is not natively supported in C++. and workaround require to know at least one list of possible arguments. so `adaptee_type` seems required. you might move all specific stuff from inside `Adaptater` class, but not sure you gain something with that.

Comment: How would a possible workaround roughly look like if `adaptee_type` is allowed to be modified?

Comment: @StefanKssmr: [Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9997a68d6780164) showing specific stuff "outside" `Adapter`. but as I said it is similar to your version.

Comment: @Jarod42 Still an improvement, though.